# Get the data of a previous row/last row inserted using TRIGGER Function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get the data of a certain column of a previous row and insert it in a new row using `TRIGGER Function`? I've tried the `LAG()` function but it is not allowed in the `INSERT` statement.

For example:

I have a Position_History table

| StartDate | EndDate | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 12-12-2020 | Developer |

What I want is to get the previous data of EndDate and put it in StartDate  column. Like this.

| StartDate | EndDate | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-12-2020 | 12-13-2020 | Developer |

I used GETDATE() on EndDate column.

Comment: Please, provide your query and example of the data

Comment: What do you mean by previous row? last row inserted into this table?

Comment: Yes, last row inserted. Sorry for a confusing question

Answer (score 0):

Try using a column

```
 --- some Table ---
 ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
 ....
```

Then your previous line would be (by definition) ID-1. Quite simple actually, if you think about it ("the one just before id=544 is id=543"). That's why 90% of the tables I know have such an identity column (yes, the concept has a name).

Things you would want to think about - 1. what if you delete a certain row? do you still want the following line to point to a non existing row? Hard to tell. 2. Is your data constantly correcting itself (like a list of users, constantly changing their passwords, details and what have you not). Do you really want each person to point to the previous updater or to the last new user? does it change in time or just the last one when he registered? 3. What happens if two people sign up simultaneously? do they point to the same last person?

Comment: 1. You cant delete a row
2. The data cant be corrected. It just gets the datetime. So no correction of data.
This is Position_History table by the way.

Comment: @WannaBeProg, then identity column is the choise for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a temporary table to insert all the previous data, then sort it with the appropiate criteria, and finally getting the record you need using the recordcount - 1.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `lag()` in an `update` as follows:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ph.*,
             lag(enddate) over (partition by position order by enddate) as prev_enddate
      from position_history ph
     )
update toupdate
    set startdate = prev_enddate
    where startdate is null and prev_enddate is not null;
```